# Shell script read variable from txt file?

Tags: bash, shell

i have a text file that looks like this:

test.txt:

```
date="2015-01-02"
week="3"
```

I also have a shell script that takes in the variable form the above text file:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
source test.txt
echo $week
```

When i run `./test.sh`, i get this error:
`week: command not found`

I thought i could follow this elegant solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367136/how-do-i-read-a-variable-from-a-file

but it seems like that only works for bash script.

How do i do it for shell script?

Comment: It works fine for me. Put `set -x` at the beginning of `test.sh` to see all the commands as they're executed.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a space after `week`?

Comment: The error you report would happen if you have a space between `week` and `=` in `test.txt`.

Comment: so sorry there were spaces in my file. Thanks for spotting the mistake

Comment: Your question is unclear. Bash is a strict superset of Bourne shell; the `source` synonym for `.` (dot) is Bash-only, so you need to change that for `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "source" statement may be having a path issue.
Consider the following output:

I added a few commands, like ps -f (to convince myself it really was running in sh, not bash).  And some echos to indicated what is going on.

(as an after thought, I also tried it with "xyz.txt" instead of "bar.sh", still same behavior.)

### output

```
sh-4.1$ ./foo.sh
--- begin ps ---
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
userabc   3352  3350  0 18:05 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
userabc   3523  3352  0 18:09 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
userabc   3778  3523  0 18:18 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./foo.sh
userabc   3779  3778  0 18:18 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
--- end ps ---
Trying just 'bar.sh'
./foo.sh: line 8: source: bar.sh: file not found
week=
date=
Now trying './bar.sh' (note the leading ./ )
week=3
date=2015-01-02
Done.
sh-4.1$
```

The big difference is the two source statements; looks like source needs a qualified path.  Usually I would just say **. ./bar.sh** but that is more or less habit because I always use ./whatever.sh to invoke a given shell script.

Test scripts follow...

### foo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo --- begin ps ---
ps -f
echo --- end ps ---

echo "Trying just 'bar.sh'"
source bar.sh
echo week=$week
echo date=$date


echo "Now trying './bar.sh' (note the leading ./ )"
source ./bar.sh
echo week=$week
echo date=$date

echo Done.
```

### bar.sh

```
date="2015-01-02"
week="3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test.txt is fine.

For test.sh, change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./test.txt
echo $week
```

Output is:
3